# Does an end user need sl4a installed to use python-android apps?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I am currently learning how to code in Python. My goal as of right now is to learn how to write apps for Android.

Recently, I have been thinking about switching over to Java. However, since I am a beginner I find Python comes relatively easy to me. If I write an Android app in Python using sl4a, does the end user need to have sl4a installed for the app to work?

If so, I think I am just going to start learning Java. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [sl4a](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) requires the sl4a app to be installed on the user's Android device.

sl4a is essentially a runtime application that needs to be installed before the user can run your app built and run on top of sl4a.

AFAIK sl4a is not just for Python but other languages too.

**Update:**

If you're looking to build cross-paltform (*Mobile*) apps in Python; IHMO the best option for this right now is [Kivy](http://kivy.org/). I'd encourage any Python developer wanting to get into the Mobile platform space to look at this :)

Comment: damn alright, so i should just start learning java for android app dvelopment, right? since there's no other way

Comment: Just to add to this in the context of the original question, kivy does *not* require any external dependencies, it builds fully standalone apks.

Comment: While Kivy is an impressive option. The requirements on OS, Python version (2.7), and the amount of work required to install Kivy turned me off of it.